# 2D array in C and warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, 2d

I do not write in C often and am having some trouble. For starters I think I am sure I am putting lines I am reading in from textfiles into a 2D array correctly. Also I am having a problem when I try and put the line into the array. I get a warning that the assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast. I want it to be a char and I think thats why I am getting a Seg Fault since it is bigger than the size i allocated. I have included my code below. I bet this is a stupid mistake, I havent  used C in a while thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
FILE *fid;
char line[70];
char dna[66800][70];

main() {
    int counter = 0; 
    fid = fopen("dna.fna","r");
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fid) != NULL){
        //fputs ( line, stdout ); 
    dna[counter][0] = line;   //Getting a Seg Fault here     
    counter++;
    }

    fclose(fid); 

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assignment in this case should actually be a copy, like this:

```
strncpy(dna[counter], line, sizeof(line));
```

The warning you are getting is caused by `line` being decayed into a pointer and trying to assign that to a `char`.

You also have to be sure that `counter` will never exceed 66800.